# NuxtJS| load component in header component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'm currently busy creating a NuxtJS app. In this app I have a header with a header component which is working as intended. But I want to add a feature for my sub pages. The header always has the same style but the content should be different. How would I be able to load the correct content component in my header component based on the page? For example like this my nuxtjs structure is as follows:

pages/index.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Header/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Header from '~/components/Header.vue';

    export default {
        components: {
            Header
        }
    }
</script>
```

`
This should load my header.vue with the content for the homepage so for example my /components/header.vue should look something like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <header class="hero is-fullheight">
            <div class="hero-head has-background-white">
                <Menu />
            </div>
            <div class="hero-body">
                <div class="container fluid">
                    <HomepageContent />
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Menu from '~/components/header/Menu.vue';
    import HomepageContent from '~/components/header/HomepageContent.vue';

    export default {
        components: {
            Menu,
            HomepageContent
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .hero {
        background-size:cover;
        position:relative;
    }
</style>
```

As you can see it should load the component homepageContent. But when I load my header.vue from a subpage, for example 'about-me' it should load the component AboutMeContent.vue

I have been on this problem for a few hours now and I can't find a useful solution to this. Anybody here who would be able to help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for slots. Docs can be found [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html)

Example

```
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <slot name="header"></slot>
  </header>
  <main>
    <slot></slot>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <slot name="footer"></slot>
  </footer>
</div>

<base-layout>
  <template slot="header">
    <h1>Here might be a page title</h1>
  </template>

  <p>A paragraph for the main content.</p>
  <p>And another one.</p>

  <template slot="footer">
    <p>Here's some contact info</p>
  </template>
</base-layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your HomepageContent loaded ?
If not, your `'~/components/header/HomepageContent/vue'` should be `'~/components/header/HomepageContent.vue'`

Comment: Sorry, made a typo. This component should be loaded based on the page that's calling the header.vue component. So by this I don't have to create multiple header.vue components for every different header.

Comment: if you only have a few pages, you can import all the pages into Header.vue. Then show based on page name like `<HomepageContent v-if="$route.path == 'home"></HomepageContent>`